# how to convert Lenet model h5 to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

How do I correctly convert Lenet Model (input 32x32, 5 layers, 10 classes) to Tensorflow Lite? I used this lines of codes but it gives me really bad confidences in android, [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCVHm.jpg). The confidences are all around 0.1, or 10%.

This is the code I used

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.post_training_quantize = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

The .h5 file above can predict images with good confidences and accuracy, [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRJDH.pngm.jpg). Or should I ask, does Tensorflow Lite not support custom model (Lenet)? why is tflite file does so much worse than .h5?

Comment: Why have you used post_training_quantize? You are saying that you use 32x32 images. Is it so dificult for your mobile to handle that small images? How much time does it take to process one image in your phone?

Comment: @Farmaker actually, if I delete the quantize and convert it normally, it does no difference, that's why I was wondering if tensorflow lite does not support custom lenet model. also, it only takes less than 1s to process one image.

Comment: If with quantization or not the output is the same (bad) then somewhere else is the problem. In addition transformation does not see if model is called Lenet, it just supports or not operators. So if transformation is successful there is no problem if u call it Lenet or else. You have to see if u use pixel normalization (divide by 255 or mean and std) when u transform it to bytebufer. Is everything in your mobile code the same as in computer when u manipulate images?

Comment: @Farmaker yeah i did float pixelValue = (rChannel + gChannel + bChannel) / 3 / 255.f in private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap). I tried using trained tflite model [from this link](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image) and change width/size to 224 and it works, but it only accepts 224x224 input so I'm confused why my lenet 32x32 doesnt work.

Comment: Why do u divide by 3 (/ 3 / 255f) ? This is usually for gray-scale images. I see that your images are colored.

Comment: @Farmaker ah yes you are right. i changed it to pixelValue = (rChannel + gChannel + bChannel) / 255.f now. I'm using [this mnist android app](https://github.com/frogermcs/MNIST-TFLite) to classify my leaf (mnist is grayscale, so you are right). But it still gives bad confidence.

Comment: So as per your your primary question I think we are done. There is no problem with transforming your model (with quantization or not). Next we have to see the code to debug. Is there a github link?

Comment: Thank you for the link. Is it possible to upload .h5 file and some images to check?

Comment: @Farmaker sure I just uploaded data.zip and images.zip, it also includes the python codes in case I did something wrong or you wanna train it yourself.

Comment: I see them. I will check it in a while. Have u trained it with Tensorflow version 2.2?

Comment: @Farmaker no my tensorflow is 2.1, although I usually use google colab to train too.

Comment: ok I will get back when I have results...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216351/discussion-between-farmaker-and-kvn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If .tflite file is generated with no mistakes it doesn't matter if the model is called Lenet or anything else. Also quantization will have a small decrease in accuracy but no major difference like you are stating. I would see how u are making bytebuffer to insert it inside interpreter. If u are using gray scale images u have to divide with 3/255... for colored images is only /255. If during your training u haven't used pixel normalization then do not use /255 during bitmap to bytebuffer. So your code would be like:

```
private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ModelConfig.MODEL_INPUT_SIZE);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    int[] pixels = new int[ModelConfig.INPUT_WIDTH * ModelConfig.INPUT_HEIGHT];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    for (int pixel : pixels) {
        float rChannel = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        float gChannel = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        float bChannel = (pixel) & 0xFF;
        float pixelValue = (rChannel + gChannel + bChannel);
        byteBuffer.putFloat(pixelValue);
    }
    return byteBuffer;
}
```

and not:

```
private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ModelConfig.MODEL_INPUT_SIZE);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    int[] pixels = new int[ModelConfig.INPUT_WIDTH * ModelConfig.INPUT_HEIGHT];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    for (int pixel : pixels) {
        float rChannel = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        float gChannel = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        float bChannel = (pixel) & 0xFF;
        float pixelValue = (rChannel + gChannel + bChannel) / 255.f;
        byteBuffer.putFloat(pixelValue);
    }
    return byteBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of quantization.
It reduces the size of the model so does the accuracy. Try not to quantizatise the model.
Try this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

It might increase the size the tflite model but won't degrade the accuracy to that extent.

Comment: I actually have 2 python codes that do quantize and not quantize, and both codes shrink the .h5 file to .tflite ( from 729kb .h5 to 244kb .tflite), and makes the exact same confidences. Is there any other way?

Comment: As per now, no. Will let you know if found another way and like wise.